# Questions regarding wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am a developer who has never used wordPress before and just had a couple of questions about creating a custom theme

1. To create a specific look to a website do I create a static design then inter grate it with wordpress and add the dynamic content where it needs to be added?
2. If you create a custom theme how do you make it dynamic rather then being static? When I switch themes I loose the all the appearance menu options such as (menu, widget, header and background) How do i create them?
3. For stuff like image carousels if I want the images to be dynamic do I create a widget for it in the functions.php file?
4. For all the text on the page do I just spit that out thru the visual editor?  seems to break links when editing
5. What are starter themes?

Sorry I am quite new to Wordpress but have knowledge in html, css, js and php but I just struggle to understand how to integrate a custom design and make it all dynamic

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ask [one question per post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As a first step to create a basic new template I would recommend you starting with one of the default WP themes (e.g. Twenty Fifteen), leave all the core files (they contain dynamic parts e.g. functions loading header/footer/content) and just customize the css files and images. Further customization would require changing code in php files (e.g. header.php for the header, index.php for the homepage, single.php for the article page, etc.)
2. It is true that some options related to header, background, etc. can be theme dependant, so when you change it the configuration gets lost, but the others like menus and widgets remain like they are when switching themes.
3. Yes, for stuff like carousels you usually have to use custom widgets and plugins, you can find some really good ones on the web (e.g. [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/carousel-slider/)), so you just upload the images and apply configuration in the backend.
4. Yes you use the WordPress editor (as you see it has Visual and HTML view) for all the user content within the pages and posts. Broken links might be cause of using relative paths, just make sure they are complete.
5. As mentioned in the first point you can always start with the default WordPress themes like Twenty Thirteen, Twenty Fourteeen, Twenty Fifteen etc.